# How can I generate scripts for all functions in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin version 1.10.5, and I've checked the properties and menu options but couldn't find anything on the subject.

For example, I just want to generate a script that includes the functions that I've created for my schema. If I right click on the database node and choose backup it has an option to create a script for the schema, but it creates all the objects. And I want only the functions.

Comment: Can you be more specific? WHat do you mean by "generating scripts for all functions"?

Comment: @DrColossos' answer should be what you needed. Also, if you can, install a [more recent version of pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/download/). There have been numerous improvements since v1.10. The current **version is 1.14**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no explicit switch to just export functions. I did some research since it's a nice question.

I can think of some ways to do this:

- Using pgAdmin, you get the code that makes up the function when you right-click on the function, and choose "Scripts->Ceate". You could copy&paste the contens and put it into a sql file that you can import like any other file
- Exporting the schema and importing only the functions you need (tedious, since you need the exact name and arguments of the function. [This blog post](http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/01/postgresql-tip-using-pgdump-to-extract.html) explains it:

  `pg_dump -Fc -s | pg_restore -P 'funcname(args)'`
- Do some querying in the [schema/pg_proc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html) and export the results. This could be another function that just exports the functions...